# I can't login confluence on other pc by pc's ip:8090

Tags: tomcat, confluence

I installed conflueces atlassian-confluence-5.6.4-x64.exe to my win7 pcA.

then I can open confluence in browser by localhost:8090.

But I can't open confluence in another pcB by pcA'ip:8090

Btw, pcA installed jenkins and pcB can open pcA's ip:8080

please help.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a network issue.

Maybe you have firewall turned on pcB ? Check you rules in the Firewall Settings:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7